# How to handle an error for validating between two dates?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have an jsp page where the user select between two dates. I need validation to ensure that the limit of the range is a month. I need to display message for error handling about that issue.

I tried making a function with return true and false. When the return is false, the message is already appears but system is still running to the next step. Here is my jsp page: (I use netbeans editor)

```
var fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fromTgl").value);
var toDate = new Date(document.getElementById("toTgl").value);
//call the function
var validateDate;
    validateDate = rangeWithinDates(toDate,fromDate);
//funtion for validation within two dates
function rangeWithinDates(toDate,fromDate){
      var diff = Math.abs(toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime());
      var daysDiff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

      if (daysDiff>30){
         window.alert("Please limit the date range to 1 month!");
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
 }
```

it's my full script

```
<script>
  var officeCode;
  var fdsReport;
  var rows;

  $(document).ready(function() {

    esLoadingAnimWindow("wndLoading");

      /** Get the userId from session scope **/
    var userId = "${sessionScope.UserSession.getUserId()}";
    var CurrOfficeCode = "${sessionScope.UserSession.getUserOfficeCode()}";

    if ($("#officeCode").data("kendoDropDownList") == null) {
        $('#officeCode').kendoDropDownList({
          dataTextField: "nameShort",
          dataValueField: "officeCode",
          dataSource: {
            transport: {
              read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: getFormRestUrl() + "/getListOffice?officeCode=" + CurrOfficeCode
              }
            }
          },
          optionLabel: "Select Office Code"
        });
    }

    if($("#fromTgl").data("kendoDatePicker")==null) {
      $("#fromTgl").kendoDatePicker({value: new Date(), format: "dd MMMM yyyy"});
    }

    if($("#toTgl").data("kendoDatePicker")==null) {
      $("#toTgl").kendoDatePicker({value: new Date(), format: "dd MMMM yyyy"});
    }

    $("#wndLoading").kendoWindow({
      actions: ["Close"],
      modal: true,
      width: "350px",
      resizable: false,
      title: false,
      draggable: false,
      open: function(e) { $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden"); },
      close: function(e) {
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "");
      }
    }).data("kendoWindow");

    // Call the function to stop scrolling main window when scrolling the content of kendo dropdownlist.
    stopScroll($("#officeCode").data("kendoDropDownList").ul.parent());
    });

    $("#btnProcess").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wndLoading").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

        var fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fromTgl").value);
        var toDate = new Date(document.getElementById("toTgl").value);
        var validateDate;
        validateDate = rangeWithinDates(toDate,fromDate);

        fdsReport = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: getFormRestUrl() + "/getReportFidusia?officeCode=" + $("#officeCode").val().trim() 
                                          + '&beginDate=' + dateToString($("#fromTgl").data("kendoDatePicker").value()) 
                                          + '&endDate=' + dateToString($("#toTgl").data("kendoDatePicker").value()),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }
            }
        });

        rows = [{
                cells:[
                    { value: "TN NY NN" },
                    { value: "Pemberi Fidusia" },
                    { value: "Pekerjaan" },
                    { value: "Kota Lahir" },
                    { value: "Tanggal Lahir" }
                ]
        }];

        fdsReport.read().then(function(){
            var data = fdsReport.data();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                rows.push({
                    cells: [
                        { value: data[i].tNnYnN},
                        { value: data[i].pemberiFidusia},
                        { value: data[i].jobCust},
                        { value: data[i].kotaLahir},
                        { value: data[i].tglLahir.slice(0,4) + "-" + data[i].tglLahir.slice(5,7) + "-" + data[i].tglLahir.slice(8,10)}
                    ]
                });
            };

            var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
                sheets: [
                    {
                        columns: [
                            { autoWidth: true },
                            { autoWidth: true },
                            { autoWidth: true },
                            { autoWidth: true },
                            { autoWidth: true }
                        ],
                        title: "Laporan Fidusia",
                        rows: rows
                    }
                ]
            });
            $("#wndLoading").data("kendoWindow").close();

            // Save the file as Excel file with extension xlsx
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
                fileName: "erpt_laporan_fidusia.xlsx"
            });
        });
    });

    //Ajax error listener
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError){
        //Close the loading window if it is opened
        $("#wndLoading").data("kendoWindow").close();

        //Open the alert window.
        var wndAlert = registerAlertModalWindow("wndAlert", jqxhr.responseText);
        wndAlert.center().open();
    });

    function getGLobalRestUrl() {
    return "/easy/api";
    }

    function getFormRestUrl() {
      return getGLobalRestUrl() + "/OMTRNF661";
    }

    function dateToString(pDate) {
      return kendo.toString(pDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd').trim();
    }

    function rangeWithinDates(toDate,fromDate){
      var diff = Math.abs(toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime());
      var daysDiff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

      if (daysDiff>30){
         window.alert("Please limit the date range to 1 month!");
         document.getElementById("toTgl").value = "";
         return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
</script>
```

[the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XICXI.png)
I expect if return false will display an error message and stop the running. so, the users must choose the date according to predetermined range. And if return true will be continue to the next step. Please help me to resolve this..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you show/explain where you are using the `validateDate` variable after you called `rangeWithinDate`? It look like that function is okay and your problem lies at a different place in your code.

Comment: I create my full script above.. please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validateDate doesn't prevent you from downloading: it's just an unused boolean.
If you want to, you'll have to do something like this:

```
if (validateDate){<the rest of your download code section>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset textbox value to empty and ask user to enter the value again. You can reset only last date value or both.

```
if (daysDiff>30){
     window.alert("Please limit the date range to 1 month!");
     document.getElementById("toTgl").value = "";
     return false;
}
return true;
```

In file downloading function check the value true or false

```
if (validateDate == true){
// your code
}
```

Comment: the file is still downloaded as before

Comment: Please share whole the code at the time of asking question. So we can provide you the exact result. You know you didn't share whole code. Add this before downloading file code
if (validateDate == true){
// your code
}